# Data management practices

Tags: data-format, linked-data, metadata

Software has code repositories and package managers, so installation and maintenance are done in one line (or click).

What are practices for managing data, instead? Apart from manually organized directories with readme files inside, I found a couple solutions:

- `drake` from Factual, https://github.com/Factual/drake
- `CKAN` from OKFN, https://okfn.org/projects/ckan/
- Zotero and other librarian tools, so you save datasets instead of books with them

However, `drake` is mostly about workflows, not maintenance. And `CKAN` is server-based solution for which I couldn't find a local "package manager".

What would such a package manager ideally do:

- downloading datasets from source in one click
- supporting multiple formats and conversion
- maintaining the directory structure
- updating the data from the repositories
- supporting aliases for datasets
- holding meta information about the datasets
- tags

Have you seen anything like this? If not, maybe you'd share your practices of maintaining the data manually?

Comment: you want version control?

Comment: @albert Why not? Though I found only [GitHub LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) and other solutions not integrated in data package managers.

Answer (score 4):

- `R`, the open source and cross-platform statistics software has something similar where sometimes packages/plugins for `R` include sample or test data:

  - See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391195/include-data-examples-in-developing-r-packages
  - and this info page: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html
- OKFN (the same folks behind CKAN) has something they called `Data Packages` (http://dataprotocols.org/data-packages/) which sounds like most of what you're looking for.

  - Ecosystem image from Data Packages website embedded below:

> [image: Ecosystem image from Data Packages website]

Comment: OKFN also has data package manager `dpm` (https://github.com/okfn/dpm/), though no good docs for it.